# How to apply a css tooltip only to a certain element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, tooltip, bootstrap-4

How can I apply a `margin` only to one `tooltip` element? Im using `bootstrap 4`:

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

```css
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-right{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
button{
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary applyCssToolTipHere" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [custom events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#events) provided by the tooltip component to remove/add classes:

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

$('.applyCssToolTipHere').on('show.bs.tooltip shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
  $('.tooltip').addClass('apply');
})
$('.applyCssToolTipHere').on('hide.bs.tooltip hidden.bs.tooltip', function () {
  $('.tooltip').removeClass('apply');
})
```

```css
.apply{
    background:red;
}
button{
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary applyCssToolTipHere" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button>
```